# What is the story in which a man and an alien are penpals?

Tags: story-identification, aliens

The human has a terminal disease and the alien is incarcerated. The alien has a long lifespan and he wants to travel the universe. Hence, he exchanges "souls" with the human (without the human's consent). The alien couldn't handle paper with his bare hands because he was maybe hot or radioactive. So he sent metal sheets to the human, to write on with acid. I think it is a short story from a collection, written before 90s or early 90s.

Comment: Can you make a guess as to roughly when this was published?

Comment: Is this a short story or a novel? Is there any other detail you remember? Even if you're not sure, saying “I'm not sure I remember this right, but the story might have …” can help.

Comment: Almost sounds like something that David Weber would write, but i don't know for sure.

Comment: I have added some more details. It is a short story.

Comment: I marked this one as a duplicate of the newer one because the newer one has more detail.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[A. E. Van Vogt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._E._van_Vogt), [“Dear Pen Pal”](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?70706).

[Anthologised](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?70706) in [several places](http://www.philsp.com/homeville/ISFAC/s250.htm#A4685.27).

Comment: Yes, this is the one. Thanks. I even found the [collection](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=nmuVxDED0KYC&pg=PA104&lpg=PA104&dq=%E2%80%9CDear+Pen+Pal%E2%80%9D+%C2%B7+A.+E.+van+Vogt&source=bl&ots=EJtZFCxI0P&sig=puAdINaSm-_X-wLsFW9H5BdqJVM&hl=en&ei=ggNmTqz2DYSurAe6nLGJCg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%9CDear%20Pen%20Pal%E2%80%9D%20%C2%B7%20A.%20E.%20van%20Vogt&f=false) by searching Google Books.