# Short sci-fi story about a prisoner and mind teleportation

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember studying this short story in my school book of class 9 or 10 maybe (Indian CBSE board book) in the year 2004/2005. The short story was something about two people from two different planets. They interchange messages for a while and then one of them suggests the technology of mind teleportation. One of them is a prisoner and the other one I guess is a paralysed old person. That’s all I remember.

Comment: This is a really well known story and I'm sure it's been asked about before, probably more than once, but the name of the story has slipped my mind. I think it's an Asimov story.

Comment: Aha, it's Penpal by van Vogt. It was asked about in [Short story where an alien convinces a human to exchange consciousness with it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188185/short-story-where-an-alien-convinces-a-human-to-exchange-consciousness-with-it). Let us know if this is your story and we'll mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Also asked about in [What is the story in which a man and an alien are penpals?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5373/what-is-the-story-in-which-a-man-and-an-alien-are-penpals).

Comment: And [Alien exchanges letters with human, tricks human into swapping bodies](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153219/alien-exchanges-letters-with-human-tricks-human-into-swapping-bodies).

Comment: Thank you . Yes this was what i was looking for.

Comment: @JohnRennie The story was also included in an anthology *Isaac Asimov's Sci-fi Treasury*, which may explain why you (and I) first connected it to Asimov.

Answer (score 13):

If the prisoner was an alien, this sounds like the A.E. van Vogt short story "[Dear Pen Pal](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?70706)" (1949).

From the plot summary on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dear_Pen_Pal):

> The one-sided dialog takes the form of correspondence from Skander, an alien, to an unnamed human whose replies are not presented. Skander spends some time in the first letters describing his home planet of Aurigae II, a hot planet circling a star in Auriga. Later, **Skander admits that he is a criminal**, incarcerated for conducting illegal scientific experiments. Desiring to see his pen pal, he sends several photographic sheets that can be exposed if the user simply thinks about a picture being taken.
>
> The last letter is from the unnamed human back to Skander. **The human is now in Skander's body**. He realized long ago that Skander was trying to scam him, and immediately took the "photographs" to the Earth authorities. They informed him they were **a form of consciousness transfer device** that Skander was attempting to use to escape from prison. Learning this, the human went through with the process anyway.
>
> The letter reveals that the human has a body that was **paralyzed since birth and is subject to heart attacks**. He hopes that Skander will enjoy the short time that he has left, trapped in a dying wheelchair-bound body.

Comment: FWIW, this story is available on the Internet Archive: https://archive.org/details/Out_Of_This_World_Adventures_v01n01_1950-07/page/n23/mode/2up?view=theater